# Just installed Arris Docsis 3.1 sb8200 It does NOT come with telephone connection. How can I add?

Tags: modem, cable, voice

Using Infinity, wanted to stop renting their cable modem, which has a router built-in, as well as two telephone inputs. Also did not like their router, making setting up my google mesh difficult. Got it all to work, but the new DOCSIS 3.1 SB8200 , also by Arris, has no telephone port. The new modem works great. How do I hook up a telephone, which I need for my ADT alarm system? Is there an outboard device I can get, or do I have to send back the SB8200 & what do I replace it with?

Comment: “what do I replace it with?” - One of the many Arris devices with a telephone port.  Knowing what your old modem was might help indicate what type of product you need.  I can’t recall what the ISPs call that particular type of modem currently

Comment: Thanks - I will return this one.

Comment: Yes; You should; Arris indicates voice capability with SBV for their DOCSIS 3 product-line.  However, unless you have digital VOIP services it’s doubtful any of their products would support your ADT alarm system.  Artie outlined all voice supported products though [here](https://www.arris.com/globalassets/surfboard-new/allassets/arris-site-compchart-xfinitycustomers.pdf) Xfinity but cable companies have zero options for Modems :$ **Arris is pretty much it.**

Answer (score 0):

I've used separate VOIP devices on cable modems with Comcast, and it was nothing but a bucket of trouble, so strongly recommend an integrated VOIP-ready gateway device supporting QoS (Quality of Service).  Voice is *very* sensitive to packets arriving in proper sequence, so QoS is important.

Comcast lists what they approve for endpoint devices, like the VOIP-capable gateway you want, at https://www.xfinity.com/support/articles/list-of-approved-cable-modems but it's area-specific. We can't check it because we don't know where you are. The lookup requires your address, so this is something you must do.